# Browserify - bind an action to a function

Tags: javascript, browserify

I've seen a lot of examples of using Browserify together with Backbone. What if my views aren't rendered from JS ?

I've got a simple ExpressJS app, which doesn't include any client side JS framework. How can I "link" the code in my bundled JS files from my static HTML ?

This is my JS file :

```
function doSomething() { console.log('something done'); }
```

And I'd like to have this in my HTML :

```
<script src="js/bundle.js" />
<a href="#" onclick="doSomething();">Do Something</a>
```

How can I link these ?

Comment: it seems like already have? Could you be more specific?

Comment: The doSomething function is 'bundled' inside the browserify bundle, and is defined inside an self executing anon function. So I can "get to it" if I require the relevant module, but how can I get to from the HTML ? i.e. how can I get to the global scope ?

Answer (score 0):

I just search answer for this question, and I find a clue:
In browerify's documentation, I notice there is an option:

--standalone -s  Generate a UMD bundle for the supplied export name.
                   This bundle works with other module systems and sets the name
                   given as a window global if no module system is found.

If we can build a module separately, and bind to window global variable, then we can call that module's content?

Anyone can give suggestion?